# optional where clause if the parameter is null in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to execute the whole content when the parameter is null and conditional executional execution if the parameter is given a value. The whole content is executing but the conditional execution is not working.
The code which I tried is

```
<parameter name="Application" class="java.lang.String">
<parameterDescription><![CDATA[Application Name]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
<parameter name="whereClause" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{Application} == null || $P{Application}.isEmpty() ? 
"1=1" : "((dt>= TO_TIMESTAMP($P{FromDtQry}, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss') AND dt<=  
TO_TIMESTAMP($P{ToDtQry}, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss')) AND (rv202=" + $P{Application} + ")" 
]]>
</defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
<![CDATA[SELECT id,dt,estz,evt,voc,rv201,rv202,rv203,rv204,rv205,rv40 
FROM idmrpt_cefevents_v 
WHERE 
$P!{whereClause}]]>
</queryString>
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You can always check the value of parameter(s) using the Title band, for example

Comment: Try to escape $P placeholders inside string literals with $$P.  That is `"((dt>= TO_TIMESTAMP($$P{FromDtQry}, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss') AND dt<=  
TO_TIMESTAMP($$P{ToDtQry}, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss')) AND (rv202="`